# Setting DOTNET_ROOT to directory of libhostfxr.so is insufficient

Tags: .net-core

If want to run `dotnet-trace` on Linux, against an application that ships with its own .NET Core runtime. When I run it, however, I get:

```
A fatal error occurred. The required library libhostfxr.so could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [/home/user/.net/dotnet-trace/RMBGJOBRwpkX5Kvpq_FShF5s1UmJMO8=/].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [/usr/share/dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [/etc/dotnet/install_location].
```

I located the `libhostfxr.so` library at `/home/user/app/libhostfxr.so`, then executed `DOTNET_ROOT=/home/user/app/ dotnet-trace`, but got the same error.

How do I go from the path of this library to the correct setting for `DOTNET_ROOT`?

According to `strace`, it is looking for the file `/home/user/app/host/fxr` which does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing the .NET version that matched the application I was trying to debug using [the install script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install). (I found this by using `strings libhostfxr.so`; perhaps there's a better way.)

A little confusingly, the runtime version 3.1.28 is not the same as the corresponding SDK version 3.1.422, which I installed with:

```
$ wget -O - https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --version 3.1.422
```

It can also be downloaded from [versionsof.net](https://versionsof.net/core/3.1/3.1.28/) which is not an official site, but it links to the files hosted by Microsoft.

This process installed `/home/user/.dotnet/host/fxr/3.1.28/libhostfxr.so` and I could then run `DOTNET_ROOT=/home/user/.dotnet/ dotnet-trace`.